# regexp to filter out lines in a file

Tags: regex, grep

Hi I have big file that have two kinds of lines. One that ends with `.1` and the other ends with `.2`. Now i have to filter out all the ones with `.2`.

Here are the first two lines of the file.

```
>AT1G53860.1 | Symbols:  | Remorin family protein | chr1:20107165-20109458 REVERSE LENGTH=1329
>AT1G34370.2 | Symbols: STOP1 | C2H2 and C2HC zinc fingers superfamily protein | chr1:12551002-12552501 FORWARD LENGTH=1500
```

When try to use `grep -v "\.2*" test.txt > out.txt`, i am getting both the lines. What am i doing wrong?

Thanks
Upendra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`2*` means that there may be as many twos as you want -- **including none of them!**

I suggest being a bit more precise with your regex, or you might filter out what you don't want filtered:

```
grep -Ev '^>\w{9}\.2' test.txt > out.txt
```

So, we want:

- `^` -- looking from the beginning of the line,
- `>` -- exactly one ">" char,
- `\w{9}` -- exactly nine chars or digits or underscores,
- `.` -- exactly one dot,
- `2` -- digit "2".

The argument `-E` means extended regex, so that `\w` and `{9}` would work as needed.

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. I tried this earlier `AT[1-5]G\d\.1\s[|]*` as well apart from `grep -v "\.2*"` but unfortunately none of them worked. Thanks again for the help..

Comment: @user1755155 Your first regex should have `\d{5}` instead of just `\d`. Also, you need `-E` to be able to actually use `\d`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `*` in search pattern. Following should work:

```
grep -v "\.2" test.txt > out.txt
```

**EDIT**

Moreover as pointed out by *drahnr*, above would match `.2` anywhere in the line. Looking at the specific pattern of sample input, match pattern should be modified to match `.2` only at the end of the first word in the line.

```
egrep -v "^>\w+\.2" test.txt > out.txt
```

Comment: Wrong, you need to specify somehow the beginning or it would match any occurence of ".2" within a line (not necessarily in a line that was supposed to be matched by ".2")

Comment: @drahnr Thanks for your feedback. That's true. but OP is not very specific in question. Edited ans as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Your file seems to be column based. You can also use `awk` regex to match the first column.

```
awk '$1!~/\.2$/' file
```